# Pixbuf not drawn on DrawingArea

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I'm very new to Gtk, Mono, and Gtk# in general.

Going through a lot of tutorials, examples and everything, I have managed to get an error-free code:

```
DrawingArea map = new DrawingArea ();

window.Add (map);
Pixbuf mapContents = new Pixbuf (Environment.CurrentDirectory + string.Format("{0}maps{0}1.png", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));

int wWidth = mapContents.Width, wHeight = mapContents.Height;
map.SetSizeRequest (wWidth, wHeight);
map.ExposeEvent += delegate(object o, ExposeEventArgs _args)
{
    Widget widget = (Widget) o;

    Gdk.Rectangle area = _args.Event.Area;
    widget.GdkWindow.DrawPixbuf(widget.Style.BlackGC,
                                mapContents,
                                area.X, area.Y,
                                area.Width, area.Height,
                                area.Width, area.Height,
                                RgbDither.Normal,
                                area.X, area.Y);

    _args.RetVal = true;
};
```

But, while it is error free, it also lacks the intended functionality.

What I want to do, is add background image to the DrawingArea, but it stays blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have called the `win.ShowAll()` after your code?

Comment: Don't you need to call the Repaint?